# Transform object inputstream to object file

Tags: java, android

How to transform object inputstream to object file.

I have code as below:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream myInputSttream = assetManager.open("file.zip");
File myFile = new File("/path/location/file.zip");
```

Because I have file from asset manager which the object is inputstream, but I want to use this file as object File for the purposes of algorithm code below.

Comment: what do you want to do with the InputStream once you transform it into a file.  do you want to write the File object out to somewhere else (like writing file.zip from the assetManager out to the sd card)? some clarification would be helpful

Comment: Hi sorry I just got up, then I want to extract the zip to /sdcard/
. The file is zip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to unzip files from the InputStream into files onto the SDCard (per your comment), You should look at [ZipInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).  You will write something like this

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(assetManager.open("file.zip"));
```

you can then use [this code sample](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/334.html) as a guide to actually output the contents of the zip file into the SD Card